# How to apply 1D mask on 2D array in Python numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, mask

There is a 1D array of values:

```
arr0 = numpy.array([8,0,9,5])
```

There is another 2D array whose shape is `(len(arr0),3)`:

```
arr1 = numpy.array([9,5,6],
                   [2,7,4],
                   [6,7,8],
                   [1,8,3])
```

I want to create a masked array of `arr1` where `arr1[i]` is masked if `arr0[i] == 0`:

```
Result arr2 = [[9,5,6],
               [-,-,-],
               [6,7,8],
               [1,8,3]]
```

What is an elegant way to **create** this new **masked array**?

I know I can create it using a mask of shape `(len(arr0),3)`. I am hoping I can create this using a mask of shape that is just `(len(arr0))`.

Comment: Why is there any problem with just making a mask like `(arr0 * np.ones((arr1.shape[1], 1))).T`

Comment: @askewchan This is not the same as that question. It does not have a 1D array whose values are used to extract a masked array out of a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

Your mask can just set by the bool array `arr0 == 0` if you do the following:

```
In [1]: arr1 = numpy.ma.masked_array(arr1)
In [2]: arr1[arr0 == 0] = numpy.ma.masked
In [3]: print arr1
[[9 5 6]
[-- -- --]
[6 7 8]
[1 8 3]]
```

(And by the way, you need an extra set of brackets around your arr1 definition.)